# Why is chronic lymphocytic leukemia (CLL) most common leukemia in the West but so rare in Asia?

Tags: cancer, medicine

In "Advances in Chronic Lymphocytic Leukemia" (2013, Edited by Sami Malek), several times it is stated that CLL is very common in Western countries.

However, it is quite rare in Asia. (I do not have data regarding other regions in the world.)

Why would this be? I am familiar with cancers being related to lifestyle, which varies by country. (The obvious example would be how countries with high rates of smoking have higher rates of lung cancer.)

Do we have any reasons why this is? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3775563/) should help get you started. The exact reason is not yet known, but is most likely related to germline genetic differences between the two ethnic groups, as Asian immigrants to the US continue to have a low incidence of CLL.

References:

- KAWAMATA N, MOREILHON C, SAITOH T, et al. [Genetic differences between Asian and Caucasian chronic lymphocytic leukemia.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23708256/) *International Journal of Oncology*. 2013;43(2):561-565. [DOI:10.3892/ijo.2013.1966](http://dx.doi.org/10.3892/ijo.2013.1966).
- American Cancer Society: [What are the risk factors for chronic lymphocytic leukemia?](http://www.cancer.org/cancer/leukemia-chroniclymphocyticcll/detailedguide/leukemia-chronic-lymphocytic-risk-factors)